# Java plugin pop-up menu

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin which adds a view. This view contains a table which contains on each row some informations. I would like to have a popup menu when I press the right mouse click. 
How can I add the extension org.eclipse.ui.menus and after creating the menuContribution to see it in the view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ViewPart` use this code:

```
MenuManager contextMenu = new MenuManager();

contextMenu.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);

getSite().registerContextMenu(contextMenu, viewer);

Control control = viewer.getControl();
Menu menu = contextMenu.createContextMenu(control);
control.setMenu(menu);
```

where `viewer` is your `TableViewer`.

The context menu this creates has the same id as your view so you contribute to it with:

```xml
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:your.view.id">
     ....
  </menuContribution>
```

Comment: My table is defined like this : Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.SINGLE);  , how to define the TableViewer ?

Comment: Just use `table` instead of `control`